# R vector strings to be objects in a list

Tags: r, dataframe

I have five data frame objects in R:

```
a,b,c,d,e
```

for　example:

> ```
> a=data.frame(a=seq(1:100))
> b=data.frame(a=seq(1:200))
> c=data.frame(a=seq(1:200))
> d=data.frame(a=seq(1:300))
> e=data.frame(a=seq(1:400))
> ```

I have the string name of them in a vector:

> df=c('a','b','c','d','e')

In fact I want these to be a list with five dataframes,like:
`ld=list(a,b,c,d,e)` and
the name of each dataframe should also be

```
'a','b','c','d','e'
```

I try:

> ```
> aa=paste0(df,collapse = ',')
>
> bb=list(eval(parse(text=strsplit(aa, ",")[[1]])))
> ```

however failed.
Thanks for anyone who answers my question.

Comment: Just `mget(df)`

Comment: Much brilliant of you! Thank you! It seems that I was in a new world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `setNames(lapply(df,get),df)`.